# How can I update a user in my DB after a purchase?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\core\init.php';

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 10;

$stripe = array(
"secret_key" => "sk_test_vDYOBYxCErhrgGCeWQJhR4mQ",
"publishable_key" => "pk_test_4mIuE3OsajKO4cnFppcDDISu"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=blog', 'root', '******');

$userQuery = $db->prepare("
SELECT id, username, email, premium
FROM users
WHERE id = :user_id
");

$sql = "UPDATE users
    SET premium = 1
    WHERE id = :user_id";

$userQuery->execute(['user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);

$user = $userQuery->fetchObject();

?>
```

How can I update a certain user after they purchase premium?

This is the only way I could get it to work.

I want to update the user by username or email, but I'm failing. I want it to pull the email/username of the account signed in during a purchase, so it'll update in my database right after & won't update the wrong person, or worse everyone!

Comment: You should only update the user by these other fields if they are unique (e.g. there can't be two users with the same email, or two users with the same username) - I expect they almost certainly are unique, but its worth thinking about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will set the variable "premium" to 1 based on a given e-mail address. Note that e-mail needs to be unique, otherwise all users with that e-mail address will become premium

```
$sql = "UPDATE users
SET premium = 1
WHERE email = :user_email";

$userQuery->execute(['user_email' => $theEMailAddressOfTheUserThatPurchasedPremium]);
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to PHP, how would I define them? $user_email = "email"; & the other long var as user_email? I also get this error, Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, Thanks in advance!

Comment: From somewhere you need to get the e-mail address of the user. That variable needs to be put instead of the long variable from the answer

Comment: Not trying to annoy you/have you spoon feed me through this, but how can I do that? Stripe receives the email in order to make the purchase, I also have a reg/login page. I've tried using the get method and post to retrieve the email. I've tried using the info on the login page I have, but it just redirects me to my login page when I require it. If you know any tutorials on this, that'd be great. I'm sure you know how to do it, but I don't want you to feel like I want someone else to do it for me. I've searched Google & YouTube, I assume I'm searching the wrong stuff. :|

Comment: Hi, I think the best approach is to dive into PHP: http://goo.gl/PqiRi4.
After you understood the basics make yourself familiar with the Stripe API. Especially the [retrieve Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#retrieve_customer) method looks promising for your problem.